# Lower speeds while copying data to a thumb drive

Tags: usb-drive

I have experienced this issue with almost all versions of ubuntu. It happens with all types of thumb drives. I have faced same issues with all the pc's I have used. At the beginning it seems like data is getting copied with a reasonable speed but after few seconds it slows down, and progress bar even stops intermittently. In comparison to speeds on windows, it is terribly slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it could be any one of the following bugs [591174](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/591174) [541937](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/541937) or [197762](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/197762)

Comment: you can try to use cp and compare the speed sometimes this helps. This bug really annoyes me since Intrepid.